# How to create logarithmic scale in chart.js with normal numbers?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

How to create a chart.js with logarithmic scale on xAxis with normal numbers instead of "1e+0" etc.? Here's my code:

```
/* eslint-disable */
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';

Chart.plugins.register({
  beforeDraw: function (chartInstance) {
    const { ctx } = chartInstance.chart;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, chartInstance.chart.width, chartInstance.chart.height);
  }
});

const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        legend: {
          display: false,
          position: 'bottom',
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
                callback(tick) {
                  return `${tick}%`;
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          xAxes: [
            {
              display: true,
              type: "logarithmic",
            }
          ]
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label(tooltipItem, data) {
              const dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
              const currentValue = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
              return `${currentValue} %`;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  },
};

/* eslint-enable */
```

And mine chart:
[image]

Appearently all the values are on the same x dont konw why also. Version of chart.js: 2.9.3 (it cannot be changed). Thanks for any advice and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tick callback to transfrom it to a normal number again:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'logarithmic',
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (val)
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```